# How to change Name of play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

i developed a web app using **`play framework 2.1.2`** and now after development of application i want to **change name of application**.

first i set name using **command** :  `$ play new bot`

**now my web app name** is : `bot` but i want to change it to `securebot`.

so **how to change Name of application?**

Give me some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it in the `project/Build.scala` file.

Answer (score 1):

For Play Framework 2.2.x project name is specified in the build.sbt file located in the project's root folder.

```
name := "project_name"
```